# What does 1 in one day mean on New Users

Tags: support, new-users, user-search

When sorting [New Users by creation date](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=1&tab=newusers&sort=creationdate) each user has an entry like "1 in one day" or "16 in 31 days".

What does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

X in Y days means that the user gained X rep in Y days, where Y is the number of days since the user joined.

Answer (score 3):

It's the amount of reputation the user has earned and the number of days they've taken to achieve this.

Everyone starts with 1.